# Chrome Extension: Use Jquery unrelative to opened tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Im programing a Chrome Extension and wanted to make a Jquery Request from my background.js
I read that its not possible, and only possible from the content.js or a popup.js, but when making my request it can be that the user closed the page, where the content.js was running (same for the popup), so how do I handle this?

PS: Im using V13

Comment: Why do you need jQuery? Write your code without jQuery.

Comment: Im trying to do an AJAX Call to my server. Im sending user data, and there is not necessarily a tab opened, when I have the user data.

Comment: You don't need jQuery for AJAX calls. I don't know of any advantages using jQuery for this.

Comment: What do I use instead? Till now I only used jQuery and only found samples using jQuery?

Comment: You should use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). There is no reason to use jQuery in 2022 except some plugins. Examples using jQuery are usually really outdated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `fetch()` method:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch